# Adding ADAL to Ionic project

Tags: angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework, adal

I need help adding/integrating **[ADAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-cordova-multitarget)** to Ionic Project. Am testing with the Tabs template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADAL JS is not designed to be used in native applications. If you are interested in using JavaScript in native apps, I recommend taking a look at the [Cordova plugin for ADAL](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/04/06/adal-plugin-for-apache-cordova-deep-dive/).

Comment: Hi Sir, Its the same one am talking about, is there any way around it for IONIC apps? I have read through the thread, but it doesn't work on my app. Any guidance specific to IONIC.

Comment: Let me restate. Ionic is designed to work with angular. The ADAL flavor that works with Angular is not designed to work with native clients. JavaScript native clients support can be had by using Cordova, but that's its own approach. So no guidance for ADAL and ionic, sorry.

Comment: Thanks,much appreciated.